# Self-registering global object

Tags: c++, c++11

I am working on a library where users should be able to use static global instances. These instances (being run before main) register themselves in another global vector which can then be used...

Currently, it goes somewhat like this...

```
class A;

std::vector<A*> v;

class A {
public:
    A (int i) : i(i) {
        v.push_back(this);
    }

    int get () const {
        return this->i;
    }
private:
    int i;
};

A a(1);
A b(2);

int main ()
{
    for (A* const& c : v)
        std::cout << c->get() << std::endl;

    for (std::vector<A*>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++)
        delete *i;

    return 0;
}
```

However, I'm afraid this code will leak... even more so when I don't want users to explicitely delete the contents of the vector (they'll forget it anyway), it should happen automatically at the end of main.

Are there other solutions? I wanted to use a vector of std::unique_ptr, but apparently they don't work that way...

Comment: "*I wanted to use a vector of std::unique_ptr, but apparently they don't work that way...*" Please elaborate. Also, you __shouldn't__ be attempting to `delete` statically-allocated objects (this code does not leak as you suggest it does, but deleting objects twice invokes UB).

Comment: Since you work on static instances: a) how does that code leak and b) why on earth are you calling `delete` on  pointers which point to static objects. All in all I would say your code (as you showed us)  is buggy, but it shouldn't leak

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your code doesn't leak. The only thing that allocates memory there is `std::vector`, and it cleans itself up on destruction.
2. `a` and `b` are correctly destroyed and released at the end of execution.
3. You shouldn't `delete` things that weren't allocated with `new`.

Also, you are relying on `v` being initialised before `a` and `b` are constructed. You should lazily initialise `v` instead (see below).

```
std::vector<A*>& global_v()  
{  
    static std::vector<A*> v;  
    return v;  
}  

// use global_v() instead of v in the A constructor.
```

To get what you want, just remove the loop that deletes those objects.

[Here's](http://ideone.com/WpHgL) your code running in action with the loops removed and some debug output added. Notice that both objects are destroyed correctly.

Comment: Removing the loop that deletes those objects only gets what he wants if this is really all inside of a single translation unit -- assuming a real project with multiple translation units, there's no guarantee that `v` is constructed before objects attempt to insert themselves into it.

Comment: I think he wants users to put `new A`s in the vector but not make the user have to `delete` them.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: Where does he say that? In the first sentence he says they will be static global instances. @ildjam: True, `v` should be lazily initialised. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: So if I understand correctly there's no need to delete items from a vector with static pointers?

Comment: @Deatzo : Yes -- `a` and `b` have static storage duration, so the runtime will manage their lifetimes. The simple rule is `delete` **only** what you `new` and `delete[]` **only** what you `new[]`.

Comment: @DeatzoSeol: Correct. You *only* ever `delete` things that were allocated using `new`. You didn't allocate using `new`, so you don't `delete`. Global objects are automatically destroyed after `main`.

Comment: Also, nice with the lazy initialisation... I didn't know that! :)

Comment: @DeatzoSeol: Did you allocate those "static pointers" with `new`? No? Then you don't free them with `delete` either. The rule is very simple: if *and only if* an object was allocated with `new` should it be freed with `delete`.

Comment: @PeterAlexander It was the only explanation I could think of for him `delete`ing global variables